# Array-based queueing lock - tail overflow

Tags: arrays, locking, queue, tail, integer-overflow

I am working on an exercise given from my university regarding the implementation of array-based queueing lock.

My question is the following: what happens if the `tail` variable, responsible for giving each waiting thread their respective position, overflows? I am not referring to the `tail` variable growing over the size of the array, I am talking about overflowing as an integer.

Using mod, you find the right position a thread must have in the array, as long as the tail is not overflowed. Once it overflows though, using mod on it may point to a position that is already occupied, or it may result in leaving the next position after previous tail element unused, thus making it unable for the threads to serially unlock the array and have a normal execution.

Any advice on tackling with this?

Answer (score -1):

I think, for set number of threads calculate max value for `tail`, when no problems will be, i.e. max `tail` when `tail mod num_threads` is `0`. And then if `tail` succeeds it, set tail to `0`

in constructor I determine a max number for `tail`

```
for(unsigned i = UINT32_MAX; ; --i) // UINT32_MAX - max unsigned type value
    if(i % size == 0)//size - max number of concurrent threads
    {
        max_tail = i;
        break;
    }
```

and in `lock` method I check it

```
unsigned max = max_tail;//otherwise, may overwrite max_tail
tail.compare_exchange_strong(max, 0);
```

full code (C++17)

```
class arr_lock
{
    std::atomic<unsigned> tail;
    static thread_local unsigned slotInd;
    bool* flag;
    unsigned size;//max number of concurrent threads
    static constexpr size_t L1_cache = std::hardware_destructive_interference_size;
    static constexpr size_t mult = L1_cache / sizeof(bool);
    unsigned max_tail;

public:
    arr_lock(unsigned size_) : 
        tail(0),
        size(size_),
    {
        unsigned arr_size = mult * size;//padded for disable false sharing
        flag = new bool[arr_size];
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < arr_size; ++ i)
            flag[i] = false;        
        flag[0] = true;

        for(unsigned i = UINT32_MAX; ; --i)
            if(i % size == 0)
            {
                max_tail = i;
                break;
            }
    }

    ~arr_lock()
    {
        delete [] flag;
    }

    void lock()
    {
        unsigned max = max_tail;//otherwise, may overwrite max_tail
        tail.compare_exchange_strong(max, 0);
        unsigned slotInd = tail.fetch_add(1) % size;
        unsigned ind = mult * slotInd;
        while(!flag[ind]);
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        flag[mult * slotInd] = false;
        flag[mult * (slotInd + 1) % (mult * size)] = true;
    }
};

thread_local unsigned arr_lock::slotInd = 0;
```

Comment: How does this remotely answer the question?

Comment: I simply didn't note that didn't paste comments, why to -1?

Comment: How do you know that the OP is using C?  It's unclear to me what language they're talking about.

Comment: and what's the problem with it? I know C++, so paste C++ code. Paste Java or Python  if you want

Comment: No.  The point is to answer the question in the manner the OP specified.  Without a clear language to use, there's no real specification to go off of.